# How to return a guild's owner name

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is the piece of my code where I'm having the problem:

```
const guild = client.guilds.get('500170876243935247');
message.channel.send(guild.owner);
```

I expected it to return the owner's name, instead it says in the console that it's an empty message. I've run `guild.owner` with `console.log` and apparently it's displaying all data from the guild, emojis, member's IDs and at the end, the owner's user details, how do I display them separately?

For the record, this is the last part that I think is the focus that I need:

```
user:
 User {
  id: '317669302549XXXXXX',
  username: 'Flicker',
  discriminator: 'XXXX',
  avatar: 'a_161cc6f5d0466f7afd9a73dc2eba159d',
  bot: false,
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessage: null },
 joinedTimestamp: 1539320429681,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a User to a string, the [`User.toString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) method is automatically called: that converts the User object into a mention, like *@username*. But if you do `message.channel.send(User)` it will not call [`User.toString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) and so discord.js will be left with an object that it can't send (example for valid object: `message.channel.send(`[`RichEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed)`)`), and so the message will be empty.

To avoid this, you can try to replace the mention with something like [`User.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag): with this you also avoid being notified every time someone uses that command.
If you don't mind being notified you can use the first one when possible, otherwise the second one. Here's an example:

```
const guild = client.guilds.get('500170876243935247');
message.channel.send(message.guild.member(guild.owner) ? guild.owner.toString() : guild.owner.user.tag);
// if the user is in that guild it will mention him, otherwise it will use .tag
```

Comment: `User.toString()` will pretty never be empty it will always still try to mention the User, thing is just doing `message.channel.send(User)` will not call `.toString()` on it and so discord.js is confused and will try to convert the object but that fails and so the message errors with empty_message

Comment: Doing it like that will not call `.toString()` on `guild.owner`

Comment: It will, indeed: the argument of `message.channel.send()` will either be `guild.owner` (and so `.toString()` will be called automatically) or `guild.owner.tag` (that is already a string).

Comment: Due to `message.channel.send()` also being able to also take an Array, it will not automatically `.toString()` the input, running the code, gives me an `empty message error`  calling `toString()` is needed for example: `message.channel.send(guild.owner.toString());`even if you are not in the guild it will still send a message in the format of <@ID> ( see https://i.imgur.com/GBlROmb.png )

Comment: I tried it with my bot and got the same results, it SHOULD be right now

Comment: I moved the discussion to this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186428/discussion-between-federico-grandi-and-plasma-chicken)

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('message', msg => {
const thisguild  = msg.guild;   
const owner      = thisguild.owner.user.username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### *Discordjs v11.5.1*

In these examples `Guild` is a placeholder for where you get the guild. This can be `message.guild` or `member.guild` or just `guild` depending on the event. Or, you can get the guild by ID (see next section) and use that, too!

```js
// Get a User by ID
client.users.get("user id here");
// Returns <User>
```

**or**

```js
// Get a Member by ID
message.guild.members.get("user ID here");
// Returns <Member>
```

source: [Github](http://t.ly/xRr7p)

My way of doing it using the docs above was:

```js
let guild = msg.guild.members.get('372452704297025537');
let admin = msg.guild.member(guild);
message.channel.send(admin.user)
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```