# How to send the guild owners name?

Tags: discord.js

```js
module.exports = {    
name: 'owner',
description: "This command sends the Server Owner's Name'!",
execute(message, args) {
const guild = client.guilds.get('500170876243935247');
message.channel.send(message.guild.member(guild.owner) ? guild.owner.toString() : guild.owner.user.tag);
}
}
```

This is my code, i am using advanced command handler and this is the file for the command and i want to make a command which is &owner and it should check the guild owners name and mention it in the channel and it cant seem to work can someone help me?

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Please properly format your code using backticks and also give us some details about the issue! What happens when the code runs? What *should* happen when the code runs? That kinda thing

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you have look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089360/how-to-return-a-guilds-owner-name/56694146) already.

Your issue is that you are not using the latest syntax: `cache`

Try this:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('<guild id here>');
```

Please also make sure you use a valid guild id, as the one in the thread linked will not be one your bot is able to access.